# PROBLEMAS CON SESSIONES PHP EN CPANEL

Tags: php

Utilizando MVC PHP, tengo un Login donde creo variables de Session! Pero al querer acceder a la variable de session en otro Metodo de la clase, la session es null. como soluciono eso? en el metodo login creo las variables de session pero al querer acceder a ellas en el metodo index, la variable de session es null. en mi servidor local (WAMP) funciona todo muy bien, pero cuando cargo mi proyecto en CPanel, tengo ese problema con las variables de session.
Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?
si en el metodo de Index realizo un var_dump($_SESSION); el resultado de este es null, pero si realizo la misma operacion de var_dump($_SESSION); en el metodo de login si me devuelve el arreglo con las credenciales correctas.

```
public function login(){
        //Iniciar Sesion
        session_start();
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
            $datos = [
                'userName' =>$_POST['userName'],
                'password' =>$_POST['password'],
            ];

            //Acceder a la funcion del modelo
            if(($this->requisitoModelo->login($datos))){
                //Obtener credenciales del modelo
                $credenciales = $this->requisitoModelo->login($datos);
                $datos=[
                    'credenciales'=> $credenciales
                ];

                //Asignando Valores a variables de Sesion 
                foreach($datos['credenciales'] as $acceso):
                    $_SESSION['userName'] = $acceso->userName;
                    $_SESSION['idUnidad'] = $acceso->idUnidad;
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $acceso->password;
                endforeach;

                //Redireccionar al Index
                redireccionar('/paginas/index/'.$acceso->idUnidad);
            }else{
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Datos Incorrectos");window.location.href="https://requisitos.arsa.hn"</script>';
            }
        }else{
            $datos = [
                'userName' =>'',
                'password' =>''
            ];

            $this->vista('paginas/login',$datos);//cargar vista 
        } 
    }

        public function index($idUnidad){
        session_start();
        if($_SESSION['userName']==''and $_SESSION['password']==''){
          header("Location:".RUTA_URL);//cargar vista  
        }else{
            //Obtener los Requisitos
            $requisitos = $this->requisitoModelo->obtenerRequisitos($idUnidad);
            $datos = [
                'requisitos'=> $requisitos
            ];

            $this->vista('paginas/inicio', $datos);            
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hola @Alex, lo que te puede estar sucediendo, es que **session_start();** lo estés colocando dentro de una función y no en el comienzo del **script**. De esta forma que la estas usando  solo  incivilizas la variable de sesión para la función y no para todo el script, usandola solo una vez y no dentro de cada función.  Gracias

Comment: Hola Yoel gracias por tu tiempo, te comento que probé colocando session_start() despues de abrir <?php e incluso lo coloque en el construtor de la clase, pero en la funcion index sigue siendo null la session

Comment: ya intentaste colocar session_start() en la apertura del archivo y usar "global $_SESSION" en tu index? solo por mera prueba.

Comment: ya solucione el problema, era una configuración de la sessión en php.ini que proporciona cPanel

Comment: como solucionastes el problema de la session en el php.ini